# Unexpected Mutation Observer behavior

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, dom-events

I have an issue working with contenteditable="true".

Basically what I have is mutation observer with all options set to true.

```js
function callback() {
  console.log("callback");
}
let myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
myInput.focus();

let config/*: MutationObserverInit*/ = {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true
};

let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);

mutationObserver.observe(myInput, config);
```

```css
#myInput {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="myInput">
```

So I can handle typing, deleting part of text inside my div.

But when I try to remove all text event does not fire.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on a fiddle?

Comment: @Phiter: Not an off-site fiddle, an on-site Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Nikita - [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: A fiddle in SO would be nice because you can copy it to your own answer :)

Comment: @Phiter: Right. Again, we call them Stack Snippets. :-)

Comment: Nikita - You'd posted almost everything needed, so I went ahead and did a Stack Snippet for you. I don't see the behavior you're describing, can you update the snippet to make it a [mcve] of the problem, and/or describe the problem more thoroughly?

Comment: Thank you guys. Issue was related to other code block. Was tricky one. I didn't notice it. My fault. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to different code block. All types except characterData was filter out. I didn't notice that.